# when I check the checkbox it did not perform an event but when i reload the webpage the event performed why?

Tags: jquery

I use this

```js
$('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
  var val = [];
  val[i] = $(this).val();
  $('.lolo').append("<input class='lim' type=text value='"+val[i]+"' name='desg"+i+"' disabled='true'
                    data-role='none'/>");
                    //institute check`enter code here`
                    if(val[i]=='Dean'||val[i]=='Faculty'||val[i]=='HOD'){
    // put here list of institutes form database
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not listening to any event, that's why it executes only once. The jQuery `$` helps you to reach the value by navigating the DOM, returning what you're looking for, but it does not register any event listeners.